# ubuntu 12.04 starts up in 40 seconds, 11.10 it was 16 seconds

Tags: 12.04, startup

Both on the same laptop; any tips?? Didn't I install it right or is it because I haven't been connected to the internet and so don't have the update packages?

Wireless is disabled by a hardware problem.

Comment: Are they the same bit version (32 bit or 64 bit)

Comment: both 32 bit versions

Comment: did you upgrade? or is it a clean install?

Comment: clean install, i had 11.10 removed

Comment: but i find the wireless disabled by hardware a bigger problem

Comment: had to do with airplain mode off but i cant, also how to get drivers without internet,also never run commandos like sudo this and that, sometimes i come accross internet all kind of stuff and they say for ubuntu install run this and that commando , haha , where do you type this, in your bios ....?alt F2..man i am so nooby to ubuntu

Comment: i found out the sudo rfkill but it says dell wireless hardblocked yes softblocked yes command sudo rfkillunblock all doesnt do anything ;-( butt then i found a little button on the back of my laptop, harware wifi switch DOH, problem solved;-), now installing all the updates and i will check the start up time again

Answer (score 2):

Its still in beta and loads lots of debug stuff in background, would be correct to assess it when final version comes.